# Explicit function definition with the normal vector included

Tags: calculus

Integral of the upper hemisphere of a unit sphere at the origin: $$\int^1_{-1} \int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_0 \int^{\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}}_0 F \cdot n \; dz dy dx$$

$\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ should be the upper hemisphere of a circle (with the points that are $\in xy$-plane). Advice is telling me that, the normal vector to this function has $\langle  \cdots \hat i, \cdots \hat j, 1\hat k \rangle$. That is just confusing to me because along the points $z=0$ the normal vector should be $\sim \langle \cdots i, \cdots \hat j, 0\hat k\rangle$.

Comment: Please include quotes relevant to the question in the question, instead of links and/or images. Use links for additional context when helpful. Avoid images of text/math, since this is bad for content searches and visually impaired users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula

$$ \mathbf{n} = \left( -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, 1 \right)$$

gives a valid normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ to the surface $z = f(x,y)$ only where the function $f$ is differentiable.

In the hemisphere example, for the points where $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=0$, $f$ won't be differentiable, since the tangent plane to the surface is vertical.

We can still use the formula for points where $x^2+y^2<1$ and $z>0$. Since $f(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$:

$$ \mathbf{n} = \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, 1 \right) $$

The limit of this formula as $x^2+y^2 \to 1^{-}$ isn't helpful: it doesn't exist, but informally we can say it approaches $(\pm \infty, \pm \infty, 1)$.

But a normal vector isn't unique, since multiplying it by a scalar gives another normal vector. So let's try finding a unit normal vector:

$$ \begin{align*} \| \mathbf{n} \|^2 &= \frac{x^2}{1-x^2-y^2} + \frac{y^2}{1-x^2-y^2} + 1^2 = \frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2} \\
\| \mathbf{n} \| &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \\
\widehat{\mathbf{n}} &= \frac{\mathbf{n}}{\|\mathbf{n}\|} = \mathbf{n} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} = \left(x, y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right) = (x, y, f(x,y))
\end{align*} $$

This makes sense: at any point on a sphere, the vector to that point from the origin is perpendicular to the sphere. And this time, it's clear to see that the limit works out as expected: If $x_0^2+y_0^2=1$, then

$$ \lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0) \\ x^2+y^2<1}} \widehat{\mathbf{n}} = (x_0, y_0, 0) $$

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating over the piece of the unit sphere that lies in the first octant.  The normal at any point is the radius that ends at that point.  This means the normal at $(x,y,z)$ is $x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$